# How to see if user selection is within an HTML span

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a Firefox add-on that converts onscreen temperatures that the use highlights via the user selection. Once it is converted the user selection is replaced with a `span` HTML element with the ID of `alreadyconverted` that contains the original temperature and the converted temperature in brackets. An obvious glitch in the code is that the user can then go through and select the converted temperature and infinitely convert it.

What I want is for my Javascript code to detect when the user selection is contained within the span element, overlapping the span element or contains the entire `span` element. How can I have Javascript detect when the user has selected that `span` in full or in part?

I saw a similar question on StackOverflow, but it wanted to know when the user selection was contained entirely within the certain element. That's not completely what I want, but I'm not sure what I would need to change in the code to make it suit my needs.

View the JS Fiddle for that thread: http://jsfiddle.net/eT8NQ/

Comment: What level of granularity are you looking for? Will there be multiple other text nodes/spans on this line? Could there be multiple lines/paragraphs of text, and you only want to know about a specific span in one of them? Or is it really this case just a single line of text with one particular span?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at MDN's documentation for Select, it appears this functionality is already directly supported. See [`Selection.containsNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/containsNode).

I've [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eT8NQ/60/), and now it properly returns a boolean whether any portion of the element is in your selection.

```
function elementContainsSelection(el) {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
      return sel.containsNode(el, true);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This function is defaulted to return false unless the `aPartlyContained` flag is set. Then partial containment will also return true.

> **aPartlyContained**
>
> When true, containsNode() returns true when a part of
> the node is part of the selection.
>
> When false, containsNode() only
> returns true when the entire node is part of the selection.